# How to properly align UIButton label text with fixed image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

What is the most correct (logical, rational, elegant, understandable, right) way to align text label in the `UIButton` same way as shown in picture? Please note that text field changes in runtime dynamically. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I'd go for an `NSAttribuedString` with a `NSParagraphStyle` with indent at 80+20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make your button of "custom" type.
2. Init your UIImageView with frame (0,0,80,buttonHeight) then add as subview to your button.
3. Init your text label with frame (100,0,buttonWidth-100,buttonHeight) then add as subview to your button.